# K cross validation with different results everytime

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, data-science, cross-validation

All my models are initialized with the below:

```
def intiailize_clf_models(self):
    model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
    self.clf_models.append((model))

    model = ExtraTreesClassifier(random_state=42)
    self.clf_models.append((model))

    model = MLPClassifier(random_state=42)
    self.clf_models.append((model))

    model = LogisticRegression(random_state=42)
    self.clf_models.append((model))

    model = xgb.XGBClassifier(random_state=42)
    self.clf_models.append((model))

    model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(random_state=42)
    self.clf_models.append((model))
```

Which loops through the models and performs k fold cross validation with :

```
def kfold_cross_validation(self):
    clf_models = self.get_models()
    models = []
    self.results = {}

    for model in clf_models:
        self.current_model_name = model.__class__.__name__
        cross_validate = cross_val_score(model, self.xtrain, self.ytrain, cv=4)
        self.mean_cross_validation_score = cross_validate.mean()
        print("Kfold cross validation for", self.current_model_name)
        self.results[self.current_model_name] = self.mean_cross_validation_score
        models.append(model)
```

Anytime i run this cross validation, i get a different result even after i have set a random state on the different models. I would like to know why i get different results in cross validation and what can be done about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question.

Setting a random seed with the below solved the problem:

```
seed = np.random.seed(22)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you did not set the random_state for your k-fold generator. By default when you pass a `int` value for `cv` as

```
cross_validate = cross_val_score(model, self.xtrain, self.ytrain, cv=4)
```

`cross_val_score` will call `(Stratified)KFold` using a different random state with every call causing your model's parameters to differ leading to different results.

The relevant part from the [source file.](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c6512929f/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L316)

```
 cv: int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, default=None
        Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy.
        Possible inputs for cv are:
        - None, to use the default 5-fold cross validation,
        - int, to specify the number of folds in a `(Stratified)KFold`,
        - :term:`CV splitter`,
        - An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices.
        For int/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and ``y`` is
        either binary or multiclass, :class:`StratifiedKFold` is used. In all
        other cases, :class:`KFold` is used.
```

To remedy this you can pass your own cross-validation generator with a controlled random state as stated in the documentation above. For example:

```
# (code untested)
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=4, random_state=42)
cross_validate = cross_val_score(model, self.xtrain, self.ytrain, cv=skf)
```

Comment: sounds to me like a great answer, i get a warning though that recommends setting shuffle=True